# How to insert data into relation table from two queries

Tags: mysql, outer-join, insert-into

Wasn't sure how to write the question.

I have these 3 tables:

```
PICTURES
id
name

MATERIALS
id
name

PICTURES_MATERIALS
picture_id
material_id
```

I have thousands of pictures and 5 materials and most of the pictures have all the materials.
Using this query I've found out that about 100 pictures don't have any material.

```
select p.id, p.name
from pictures as p
left outer join pictures_materials as pm on p.id = pm.picture_id
where pm.picture_id is null;
```

What I would like to do now is to insert into pictures_materials a row for each of these pictures with each material.
So, let's say that these are some of the pictures with no materials:

```
picture_21, picture_22, picture_23
```

I want to have:

```
picture_21 material_1
picture_21 material_2
picture_21 material_3
picture_21 material_4
...
```

Is it possible to do this in a single INSERT INTO query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this in a single INSERT INTO query?

Yes!

You have found one legitimate reason to create a Cartesian product.  To do this you will use a `CROSS JOIN`.  Try this query.

```
-- insert into picture_materials
select dt.id, m.id 
from (select p.id
from pictures as p
left outer join pictures_materials as pm on p.id = pm.picture_id
where pm.picture_id is null) dt 
cross join materials
```

After validating that the Select statement returns the desired data, uncomment the INSERT statement and execute again.

Comment: thanks, this is perfect. Out of curiosity, what does 'dt' stand for?

Comment: dt - derived table.  That might be what they're called in Sybase & SQL Server.  Oracle calls them Inline Views.  I'd have to look up what MySQL calls them.  Basically you are referencing the results of a query as a table.

Comment: I knew how that works, I just couldn't figure out what the alias stood for